# How to swap the Ctrl and Alt keys in ibus?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap, ibus

I swapped both sides of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> using xmodmap. It is quite convenient to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys in Emacs, Emacs uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key a lot.

However, when I start ibus, the xmodmap stops working.

I googled and figure out that:

1. ibus overrides the settings in xmodmap.
2. xmodmap is considered obsolete.

So how to do the remappings in ibus?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `ibus-setup` and check "use system layout" (if I remember correctly), it will not override the system settings.

You mentioned that `xmodmap` is obsolete, but you may still be able to use it. You can also use `setxkbmap` or `xkbcomp`, which are not obsolete.

Comment: Yes, I've checked `Use system keyboard layout`, however, it still override the system keyboard. I guess maybe this is the problem of Gnome-shell, or ibus conflict with Gnome-shell.

Answer (score 0):

I have already faced this problem, the *Use system keyboard layout* trick didn't work, and finally I found out a temporary solution for this by making a keyboard shortcut executing a command that has two jobs:

- Send Alt + Shift keystroke to system (this key combination will change the input source of IBUS)
- Then load my xmodmap profile into system keymap

Take a look on my post for more detailed information about this solution:
http://blog.z1k.pw/?p=60